# How to troubleshoot MissingEndParenthesisInExpression in Azure Yaml Pipelines powershell task arguments

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

yaml PowerShell task looks something like this:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'test'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)\$(artifactName)\testpath\testscript.ps1'
    arguments: '-parameterFilePath $(Agent.BuildDirectory)\$(artifactName)\mainfolder\params.json -appSecurePassword (convertTo-SecureString $(appPassword) -AsPlainText -Force) -vmSecurePassword (convertTo-SecureString $(vmPassword) -AsPlainText -Force)'
```

However, I get this error:

> 2020-06-09T12:54:59.6954669Z At C:\agent_work_temp\66085384-0a17-4183-9832-42c481b13a84.ps1:3 char:352
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.6974788Z + ... urePassword (convertTo-SecureString *** -AsPlainText -Force)
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.7070327Z +                                                                          ~
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.7124752Z Missing closing ')' in expression.
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.7142356Z     + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.7161695Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEndParenthesisInExpression
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.7173148Z
>   2020-06-09T12:54:59.8102255Z ##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.

Can anyone please let me know what I am missing? I am sure there is no problem with the PowerShell script as I can run that manually on the agent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error message `... urePassword (convertTo-SecureString *** -AsPlainText -Force)` indicates the issue comes from the `arguments` of powershell task.

And the error `Missing closing ')' in expression` indicates that there is "(" character in your Password.

I tested on my pipeline, if my password is **"pass(word"**(without double quotes). I got the same `Missing closing ')'` error message.

You can try double quoting your passwords when you refer to them in the `arguments`. See below:

```
-appSecurePassword (convertTo-SecureString "$(appPassword)" -AsPlainText -Force) -vmSecurePassword (convertTo-SecureString "$(vmPassword)" -AsPlainText -Force)
```

You can also try using backtick to escape the special characters in the password. For example, escape the special characters in the Passwords defined in the pipeline Variables (eg. **"pass`(word"**)

See [Passwords Containing Special Characters In PowerShell](https://jorgequestforknowledge.wordpress.com/2011/12/15/passwords-containing-special-characters-in-powershell/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you.  This is indeed the issue with a parenthesis in the password which i did not pay attention earlier.  Added quotes around the variable and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

With Azure YAML pipelines one way to debug would be to select "Enable system Diagnostic" on your pipeline when your run:

[image]

After running it you can download the logs:

[image]

After downloading look at the azure-pipelines-expanded.yml This will be the full yaml your pipeline is running with all templates included.  This should give you a complete picture of what is being executed.

Comment: Thank you.  this is useful.