# Azure Pipeline Debug Logging

Tags: azure-pipelines

Using a YAML template, my understanding is the code below should log the parameters when I run the code with system.debug : true. Can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

```
parameters:
- name: branchName
  displayName: 'Repository branch name'
  type: string
- name: WebAppName
  displayName: 'Application name'
  type: string
- name: ServiceConnection
  displayName: 'ServiceConnection name'
  type: string
- name: Workspace
  displayName: 'Workspace name'
  type: string
  
  ##[group]Beginning of a DeployTemplate Parameters
  ##[debug]Debug branchName: ${{parameters.branchName}}
  ##[debug]Debug WebAppName: ${{parameters.WebAppName}}
  ##[debug]Debug ServiceConnection: ${{parameters.ServiceConnection}}
  ##[debug]Debug Workspace: ${{parameters.Workspace}}
  ##[debug]Build.SourceBranchName: variables['Build.SourceBranchName']
  ##[endgroup]
```

Comment: Try referencing this previous answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/62287825/8446413

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested the following script, on my side, the parameter value is displayed normally in the log. Did you set the defalut value for the parameter in the template file or pass the value to the parameter in the pipeline yaml?

Parameter template yaml:

[image]

Pipeline yaml:

[image]

Logs:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Hugh! After seeing your code, I recognized my mistake. I wasn't using a power shell task. I was under the impression the Agent just picked up the commands so what like compiler commands. After reading you response, the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/logging-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=powershell made more sense. Thank you.